# How to make Popup window always on top

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I want to open a popup window which should be on top when ever a link from its `parent` page is clicked. For example when I click on a link (on a parent page) a popup window open and when I click on another link of parent page the previous popup window become on top of that parent page (and all other open browser's windows)

I have tried the following codes in that popup window HTML but with no luck.

```
<body onLoad="window.focus();">
```

and

```
<body onLoad="self.focus();">
```

and

```
<body onBlur="self.focus();">
```

Neither of these works. I am using Chrome browser if that helps. Please help!

Comment: You cannot reliably force a client to raise a window to the top. Some will, some won't. You really can't even guarantee that a new window won't simply be a new tab.

Comment: FYI - it should be `onload` and `onblur` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ: Tried changing the code as you suggested, it didn't worked either.

Pointy: How can I make it so that it should be on focus when a link is clicked from its parent page?

Comment: @The One and Only ChemistryBlob: Yes tried that too, it didn't worked

Comment: I believe I have dabbled with this on my site and at the least you need to refer to the popup window name and focus it: window.open('', 'myPopup', '').focus();

Comment: Can you simply bind the following everytime a link is clicked: close the popup and re-open it ? This way it's guaranteed to have focus

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding `.focus()` at the end of your popup window javascript (just before `;`)